# Gnome keyring and external storage

Tags: security, gnome-keyring

I have an application, which is using gnome keyring for storing its passwords/credentials and those are stored into `~/.local/share/keyrings/`. Therefore I am wondering if it would be possible to change keyring backend to "exteranl storage"? By external storage I mean for example SoftHSM2 or any other PKCS#11 compliant storage.